# write read-only ACPI tables

Tags: bios, clover, acpi, rootkit

I wanted to modify my ACPI tables from some simple kind of rootkit before Windows boots.

->no, I can't alter the BIOS code

->I know Clover is able to do the job, but I'm booting legacy mode and didn't manage to install it for legacy devices, yet

but now I started myself with the RSDP pointer:

->int 15h E820 reports it's memory region as "**Type 2: Reserved - unusable**"

And that seems to hold true, for I cannot write it. I assume it's not hard coded into BIOS but written at boot-time, so my conclusion was i had to program the DRAM controller...

Is there a common way to program the DRAM controller to get write access at these regions for kinda all platforms as INTEL32 and AMD64?

or any other method to get write access at ACPI tables?

**Edit 1:** EBDA is write-protected by PAM-registers and TSEG prevents from writes to higher regions such as ACPI tables.
What's the equivalence at AMD64 platform to these?

Comment: I didn't get in where in the chain of loading is your software being located?

Comment: I thought I just could copy the Master Boot Record to another sector at my main disk, first boot my own stuff and after that load the original MBR at 7C00h and continue to Windows as usual

Comment: Yes, you need to program MMU correctly. Note, there is no protection for the loader (it runs at ring 0 privileges). You may look to the source code of boot loaders that does create ACPI tables (like U-Boot).